# Wrong distance between two points in Geodjango

Tags: django, geodjango

I have user class:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    location = PointField(srid=4326)
```

and I calculate distance between two points in serializer this way:

```
obj.location.distance(request.user.location) * 100
```

For example I have two points:

```
POINT(-95.3385 29.7245)
POINT(-85.3385 29.7245)
```

One point is for authorized user the other is for the other user.

Serializer returns 1000 kilometers. I don't know what is latitude and longitude and it doesn't matter because in online calculators in one case it is a little bit more than 1000 km and in the other - a little bit less than 1000 km. And it is never 1000 km.

Any ideas why this is happening?